# Explanation of the schematic for the BQ25703A charger

Tags: battery-charging, solar-charge-controller, lithium

I am trying to build my solar charger to charge my lithium batteries. The lithium batteries already have a BMS on them. I am using the BQ25703A IC from Texas Instruments.

**Datasheets:**

[BQ25703A](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq25703a.pdf?ts=1711196910622&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fpower-management%252Fbattery-management%252Fcharger-ics%252Fproducts.html)
[BQ2570X EVM](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/sluubg6/sluubg6.pdf)

**My questions:**

1. What is the purpose of having two grounds? I do not see any isolation on the IC and also the VSYS and VBAT are both referenced to the PGND.

[image]

2. The datasheet says to connect the 1uF cap to the power ground, why then does the schematic connect to the other ground?

[image]

[image]

3. The PGND has the symbol for the GND, should the symbol change, or should it be renamed to GND?

[image]

4. What is the purpose of the circuit close to the input, what do Q9A and Q9B do?

[image]

Comment: The BQ25703A datasheet has section _11.1 Layout Guidelines_ which contains ``Route analog ground separately from power ground. Connect analog ground and connect power ground separately. Connect analog ground and power ground together using power pad as the single ground connection point. Or using a 0-Ω resistor to tie analog ground to power ground (power pad should tie to analog ground in this case if possible)``. Does that help to answer the question about why there are two ground ``GND`` and ``PGND`` net names shown on the schematic? ``NT1`` (Net-Tie) ties ``GND`` and ``PGND`` together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the purpose of having two grounds? I do not see any isolation on the IC and also the VSYS and VBAT are both referenced to the PGND.

Electrically, the two grounds are not isolated, yes.

Power ground `PGND` carries large, switching currents whilst the signal ground `GND` carries relatively small currents and also it's the reference for sensitive digital communication lines (e.g. I²C).

There's a possibility of having the `PGND` "move" up/down because of those large currents if the layout is done improperly (The effect can be more pronounced in cases with large "surge" currents). Also, even if the power ground is at 0V potential the return currents contain high-frequency components due to the switching operation.

Now the purpose of separating these two grounds is to prevent the related signals and sub-circuits from interfering with each other. If `PGND` and `GND` are shorted at a random location (e.g. using the same trace for both) to allow the large return currents to flow through the signal ground reference then a risk of having the small signals *lift* may arise. Noise coupling is another possible issue.

But it may not always be a good idea to keep them separated because, in some applications, the potential difference between the two grounds may cause some other problems. So the best method is to follow the datasheet recommendation. In your case, it's separation: Separate the power and signal grounds, and join them together at a single point, preferably at supply input ground (Research term: star grounding).

> The datasheet says to connect the 1uF cap to the power ground, why then does the schematic connect to the other ground?

I haven't checked the layout thoroughly so I can't give an exact answer. If the C29's GND connection is very close to the GND-PGND junction (tying point) it might be beneficial to connect the SGND for an easier layout as the C29's GND would still be virtually connected to the PGND. The PCB images [here](https://www.ti.com/tool/BQ25703AEVM-732) may give an idea, or you can dive into the details by looking at the PCB design files (gerbers) if published or publicly available.

> The PGND has the symbol for the GND, should the symbol change, or should it be renamed to GND?

PGND is still PGND. What matters for Altium is the net names. Don't get confused by the symbols. Apparently, they used a separate symbol to indicate the return path of the large and switching currents (The MOSFETs and input/output connectors).

> What is the purpose of the circuit close to the input, what do Q9A and Q9B do?

Q5-Q6 pair is a PMOS bidirectional switch. PMOS requires negative Vgs to turn on (gate voltage lower than source voltage). Q5's gate is grounded, and when the power is first applied the body diode will be forward-based making the source voltage almost equal to the input voltage. So Q5 will turn on, then Q6 will turn on.

To turn them off, Q9A is used i.e. to short the source pin to the gate pin (via a 10R resistor, actually). It's PNP, so Q9B is used as a kinda voltage translator to turn it on by default. If `CHG_OK` is applied Q9B will be off, leading to the turn-off of Q9A making the Q5-Q6 pair on.

Answer (score 3):

> *What is the purpose of having two grounds?*

The best way to think about this is that the PGND pin is the star point to which all grounds (power and non-power) connect. Page 23 of the [data sheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq25703a.pdf?ts=1711196910622&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fpower-management%252Fbattery-management%252Fcharger-ics%252Fproducts.html) shows this in more detail: -

[image]

As you can see, inside the device the "true" star point is made hence, when you ask about VDDA and the 1 μF capacitor, the best place to connect it is at the PGND pin. I see that the evaluation board does this using a net tie NT1 to separate PGND and GND. That's one way of doing it. My preferred way is to star point at PGND directly.

> *What is the purpose of the circuit close to the input, what do Q9A and
> Q9B do?*

- Q5 and Q6 form a bidirectional switch. This can turn off charging from the left and, also prevent over-discharge from the battery on the right
- Q9A being activated open-circuits the bidirectional switch
- Q9B activates Q9A and provides a 0 volts referenced control interface to facilitate this

Comment: But standard practice is to always use a GND copper plane under. In addition instead of routing GND you would just drop a via close to the pad requiring a GND connection. So instead of routing GND and PGND is it better to just use a ground copper pour underneath? By underneath I mean for example for a 2 layer PCB, layer 1 will be power and signals and layer 2 will just be a solid ground copper plane.

Comment: @JoeyB standard practice is what it is (standard). For this type of situation where you do need to keep power currents away from sensitive ground connections, you employ the concept of a star point and join the sensitive part of the ground plane to it at one point. That's my advice anyway.

Comment: The sensitive area can still form an island plane but, it gets grounded at the star point.

Comment: Thank you Andy!